# WSO2DAS Dashboard issue

Tags: wso2, wso2-das

I've created a gadget on WSO2DAS, it is visible in store, but can't find it in list "Add Gadgets" while creating the dashboard.

Any help  appreciated.

Comment: What is the WSO2 DAS version you are using?

Comment: i am using wso2das-3.1.0

Answer (score 0):

Maybe is not a valid answer but instead a workaround. I am facing the same issue but recently I found that, if you add another gadget, the dashboard wizard show the first gadget added before the last one. The last added gadget is not show by the dashboard wizard.